How do i create a fluentcrm custom plugin on wordpress that allows for me to have two user roles; the super admin and the company/client
The roles should allow for creation of companies with contacts that can be linked to them, contacts and email campaigns as well as managing the contacts, campaigns and automation of e-mails. Meanwhile, users that log in with a company/client user role should be able create their own contacts on the wordpress dashboard that will be only related to their own companies without being able to access the contacts of other companies. I have added some of these functionalities to some extent but I am having issues creating my contacts with their details when logged in as a company/client user role on the company/client dashboard.
I have tried adding the necessary functionalities and capabilities for each roles while making them have their own access to their respective dashboard. You can see the code below
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Fluent CRM
Description: A custom CRM plugin for managing companies, campaigns, and contacts.
Version: 1.0
Author: Kaytech
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

// Plugin Initialization
function custom_fluent_crm_init() {
    Super_Admin::init();
    Company_Client::init();
    Company_Management::init();
    Contact_Lists::init();
    Campaigns::init();
    Surveys::init();
    Reports::init();
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'custom_fluent_crm_init');

// Allow custom roles access to the dashboard
function custom_fluent_crm_allow_dashboard_access() {
    if (current_user_can('super_admin') || current_user_can('company_client')) {
        show_admin_bar(true);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_fluent_crm_allow_dashboard_access');

// Create necessary database tables
function create_plugin_tables() {
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $company_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_fluent_crm_companies';
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $company_table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        company_id tinytext NOT NULL,
        logo text,
        phone tinytext,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_plugin_tables');

// Super Admin Class
class Super_Admin {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_init', array(__CLASS__, 'add_roles'));
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_roles() {
        add_role(
            'super_admin',
            'Super Admin',
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'manage_options' => true,
                'create_companies' => true,
                'assign_plans' => true,
                'view_reports' => true,
                'manage_users' => true,
            )
        );

        add_role(
            'company_client',
            'Company Client',
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'manage_contact_lists' => true,
                'view_campaigns' => true,
                'view_reports' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Super Admin Dashboard',
            'Super Admin',
            'manage_options',
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            array(__CLASS__, 'dashboard_page'),
            'dashicons-admin-users',
            2
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Companies',
            'Manage Companies',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_companies',
            array('Company_Management', 'manage_companies_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Campaigns',
            'Manage Campaigns',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_campaigns',
            array('Campaigns', 'manage_campaigns_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Surveys',
            'Manage Surveys',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_surveys',
            array('Surveys', 'manage_surveys_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'View Reports',
            'View Reports',
            'view_reports',
            'view_reports',
            array('Reports', 'view_reports_page')
        );
    }

    public static function dashboard_page() {
        echo '<h1>Super Admin Dashboard</h1>';
    }
}

// Company Client Class
class Company_Client {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Company Dashboard',
            'Company',
            'manage_contact_lists',
            'company_dashboard',
            array(__CLASS__, 'dashboard_page'),
            'dashicons-building',
            3
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'company_dashboard',
            'Contact Lists',
            'Contact Lists',
            'manage_contact_lists',
            'contact_lists',
            array('Contact_Lists', 'contact_lists_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'company_dashboard',
            'View Campaigns',
            'View Campaigns',
            'view_campaigns',
            'view_campaigns',
            array('Campaigns', 'view_campaigns_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'company_dashboard',
            'View Reports',
            'View Reports',
            'view_reports',
            'view_reports',
            array('Reports', 'view_reports_page')
        );
    }

    public static function dashboard_page() {
        echo '<h1>Company Dashboard</h1>';
    }
}

// Company Management Class
class Company_Management {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
        add_action('admin_post_save_company', array(__CLASS__, 'save_company'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Companies',
            'Manage Companies',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_companies',
            array(__CLASS__, 'manage_companies_page')
        );
    }

    public static function manage_companies_page() {
        echo '<h1>Manage Companies</h1>';
        // Add form and logic for managing companies
    }

    public static function save_company() {
        check_admin_referer('save_company_nonce');
        // Save company data to the database
    }
}

// Contact Lists Class
class Contact_Lists {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'company_dashboard',
            'Contact Lists',
            'Contact Lists',
            'manage_contact_lists',
            'contact_lists',
            array(__CLASS__, 'contact_lists_page')
        );
    }

    public static function contact_lists_page() {
        echo '<h1>Contact Lists</h1>';
        // Add form and logic for managing contact lists
    }
}

// Campaigns Class
class Campaigns {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Campaigns',
            'Manage Campaigns',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_campaigns',
            array(__CLASS__, 'manage_campaigns_page')
        );
    }

    public static function manage_campaigns_page() {
        echo '<h1>Manage Campaigns</h1>';
        // Add form and logic for managing campaigns
    }

    public static function view_campaigns_page() {
        echo '<h1>View Campaigns</h1>';
        // Add logic for viewing campaigns
    }
}

// Surveys Class
class Surveys {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'Manage Surveys',
            'Manage Surveys',
            'manage_options',
            'manage_surveys',
            array(__CLASS__, 'manage_surveys_page')
        );
    }

    public static function manage_surveys_page() {
        echo '<h1>Manage Surveys</h1>';
        // Add form and logic for managing surveys
    }
}

// Reports Class
class Reports {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(__CLASS__, 'add_menu_pages'));
    }

    public static function add_menu_pages() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'super_admin_dashboard',
            'View Reports',
            'View Reports',
            'view_reports',
            'view_reports',
            array(__CLASS__, 'view_reports_page')
        );

        add_submenu_page(
            'company_dashboard',
            'View Reports',
            'View Reports',
            'view_reports',
            'view_reports',
            array(__CLASS__, 'view_reports_page')
        );
    }

    public static function view_reports_page() {
        echo '<h1>View Reports</h1>';
        // Add form and logic for viewing reports
    }
}
?>


firstly you don't need to create mysql table, you can use wordpress function to create custom post types and manage capabilities with that : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

secondly, it's better to separate each question on stackoverflow. then edit your question to ask only about 1 problem with details, debugging, etc. and when it's solved you will create a new question for the next problem.

Small nitpick. WordPress actually has “Super Admins”, so creating a role with that name might confuse other developers some day in the future. It isn’t technically a “role” in the traditional sense, and it only comes into play for multi-site installs, but I would discourage the usage nonetheless
